# Assuming f and g are continuous and positive, show relation about improper integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I have proved the following result:

> Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous and positive. If $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converges and $g(x)$ is bounded, then $\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)\, dx $ converges.

I am trying to now prove the following result, using the above:

> Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous and positive. Show that if $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ and $\int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx$ converge, this does not imply $\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x) \, dx$

I was told to, in coming up with my counterexample, choose $f = g$ and using the first result to see that $f$ can't be bounded as $x \to \infty$ for this counterexample. However, I am having difficulty coming up with a counterexample to prove the second result.

Comment: Basically, you want a function f such that $\int f dx$ converges but $\int f^2(x)dx$ does not.  Yes, f cannot be bounded so you want an unbounded function whose integral, from 0 to infinity, converges anyway.  I would look for a function of the form $f(x)= x^c$ for c a real number.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = x^{-1/2}e^{-x}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: It's a bit of cheating, as the question is about infinity and not zero integral bound. Also, $x^{-1/2}e^{-x}$ isn't continuous on $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Sergei oh shoot I missed continuity. I'm used to doing everything in Lebesgue world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as it was stated in a comment, it's sufficient to find a function $f(x)$ for which $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, but $\int_0^\infty f(x)^2dx$ does not. Let's construct such a function.

Take $f(x)=n-n^4|x-n|$ for $x\in[n-1/n^3,n+1/n^3]$, $n=2,3,4...$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. So it consists of a series of triangles around $n$. The area of the triangle is $n/n^3=1/n^2$, which implies that the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

If you take $f^2(x)$ and find the area of the corresponding curved triangle around $n$, you'll get
$$
\int_{n-1/n^3}^{n+1/n^3}(n-n^4|x-n|)^2dx=\int_{-1/n^3}^{1/n^3}(n-n^4|x|)^2dx=2\int_{0}^{1/n^3}(n-n^4x)^2dx=2\int_{0}^{1/n^3}(n^4x)^2dx=\frac{2n^8}{3n^9}=\frac{2}{3n}.
$$
Hence, the integral diverges.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up making a similar argument. The only problem I had was that this function as well as the function I used are nonnegative, not positive (they equal zero at certain points). This wasn't of much concern for my problem, but a colleague of mine told me that a positive, continuous function could be made my convolving this function with a Gaussian curve.

Comment: Or just adding it to some positive function which tends to zero quickly enough, like $e^{-x}$.